# NetworkImageView always throw a NullPointerException cache.get(url) must not be null when accessing an image from a valid URL

Tags: android, kotlin, android-volley

I'm currently trying to load an image using Volley's NetworkImageView:

```
<com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
 android:id="@+id/nivCharacterDetailPhoto"
 android:adjustViewBounds="true"
 android:scaleType="fitCenter"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

And in the back-end I've set it up like this:

```
private fun setImage(view: View) {
    val photoView = view.findViewById<NetworkImageView>(R.id.nivCharacterDetailPhoto)
    val imgLoader = VolleyRequestQueue.getInstance(view.context).imageLoader
    photoView.setImageUrl("https://i.imgur.com/7spzG.png", imgLoader)
}
```

But whenever I try to load the page using this, I get a NullPointerException that cache.get(url) must not be null. The url is valid, so I surmised that the issue would need to be in the VolleyRequestQueue class. This class however, is exactly the same as the documentation describes [here](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/requestqueue).
So:

```
class VolleyRequestQueue constructor(context: Context) {
    companion object {
        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE: VolleyRequestQueue? = null
        fun getInstance(context: Context) = INSTANCE ?: synchronized(this) {
            INSTANCE ?: VolleyRequestQueue(context).also {
                INSTANCE = it
            }
        }
    }
    val imageLoader: ImageLoader by lazy {
        ImageLoader(requestQueue, object : ImageLoader.ImageCache {
                private val cache = LruCache<String, Bitmap>(20)
                override fun getBitmap(url: String): Bitmap {
                    return cache.get(url)
                }
                override fun putBitmap(url: String, bitmap: Bitmap) {
                    cache.put(url, bitmap)
                }
            })
    }
    val requestQueue: RequestQueue by lazy {
        // applicationContext is key, it keeps you from leaking the
        // Activity or BroadcastReceiver if someone passes one in.
        Volley.newRequestQueue(context.applicationContext)
    }
    fun <T> addToRequestQueue(req: Request<T>) {
        requestQueue.add(req)
    }
}
```

I know for a fact that the url is a proper string and that it is set. I used the debugger to get down to the cache.get(url) statement and again found that a string is passed to the cache.get(url) function. This time the url contains a value like: "#W1440#H1916#S3https://i.imgur.com/7spzG.png". I did however also notice that the cache is completely empty, which explains why cache.get(url) returns null. However I assume (maybe wrongly?) that using this default implementation it would try to fetch the image if none is present in the cache.

Has anyone else run into this issue? It seems to be a pretty basic one but for some reason I just can't figure it out.

I'm running on Android 11, API 30

Comment: *But whenever I try to execute this, I get a NullPointerException* no, you are not ... you are not executing `photoView.setImageUrl("https://i.imgur.com/7spzG.png", imgLoader)` but `String someStringWichIsDefinitelyNull = null; photoView.setImageUrl(someStringWichIsDefinitelyNull, imgLoader)` ... (prolly you are getting `someStringWichIsDefinitelyNull` in some async way and you don't get how callbacks are working)

Comment: I know for a fact that the the url is set, I thought of that as well because as you said, in normal circumstances I am getting that string from another API and maybe it is null at this point. But even when using the literal string pasted in there, I'm still getting the nullpointer reference.

Comment: To get back at what you said @Selvin. I wrongly said that I get the error when I execute that statement. What I meant to say is that I get the NullReferemceError when I load the page using the code written above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after a long search I eventually found the problem. The documentation is not really clear on this but:

```
override fun getBitmap(url: String): Bitmap {
    return cache.get(url)
}
```

is supposed to be:

```
override fun getBitmap(url: String): Bitmap? {
    return cache.get(url)
}
```

As the cache could return null this was causing the method to completely crash, as it's not allowed to return a nullable value. I don't know if this is only using the NetworkImageView, but should someone run across this issue again, simply make the getBimap method return a nullable Bitmap and it should work.

Comment: It's Working, Just Add `?` here Bitmap?